# iPhone Location Services is turned off, but the application can still get the location?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I turned off the Location Services on my iPhone, because I don't want the app to determine my location. But, when I run the app it somehow gets my location! Any ideas?

Comment: probably a cached location, also, `this is for highlighting code`

Comment: Please try after restart your device...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Can you please send me iOS version which you are using in your iPhone?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not cashed because I reset the device.

Comment: well one way to test absolutely is to move away from the location and see if it moves, if it doesnt, its cached for some reason.

Comment: Does the application responds with a single location or does it also shows the change in location ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs suggests [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16)

> **Locations**
>
> An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This array always contains at least one object representing the current location. If update events were deferred or if multiple events arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the end of the array.

So the location manager always shows some value.

Comment: I think you are right, I reset my phone again and it seems like it is giving me a previous location (dummy data) but not the current Location.

Thanks.